# How to change the permissions of the sound devices so only audio users can read and write

Tags: sound, permissions, filesystem, light-locker

**Summary:** I want to know how to change the permissions of my sound devices so that only my user can read and write to them. I thought this could be accomplished by `chmod 0660 /dev/dsp*` but `/dev/dsp*` does not exist.

**System Info:** Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (xubuntu)

**Detailed Problem:** I noticed that light locker stops my audio when it automatically logs me out after a certain duration of inactivity. I found an article that suggests I Add my user to the audio group (see: http://xubuntu.org/news/screen-locking-in-xubuntu-14-04/ ). I didn't know how to do that, so I found another instructional article saying I should also change the permissions of the sound devices so only audio users can read and write. It says I should execute `chmod 0660 /dev/dsp*` (see: http://www.maenad.net/geek/di8k-debian/node23.html ). However my system doesn't have `/dev/dsp*`. I want to know what the correct directory is for Ubuntu 14.04 so that I can properly change permissions as mentioned above.

Comment: Adding yourself to the `audio` group is easy: `sudo adduser $USER audio`

Comment: I would use a group (audio probably) for the device and put yourself into that group.

Comment: @muru Yes thank you, I should clarify though, I have already successfully added my user to the audio group. My problem rests in finding the correct location to chmod.

Comment: You do not need chmod. You should not change anything in /dev/

Comment: @Rinzwind, Okay I am ok with not needing to chmod if it's not needed or recommended. However if you post that as an answer I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, that's a rather *old* guide (11 years and counting). You'll find that sound devices on Ubuntu are all usually owned by `audio`: `find /dev -group audio`

Comment: @muru, your right executing `find /dev -group audio` yielded a listing of directories, all within `dev/snd`. Would it be safe to assume that an equivalent command would be `chmod 0660 /dev/snd*`?

Comment: I second @Rinzwind in that you shouldn't be touching `/dev`, but yes, the equivalent command would be that. Note that PulseAudio runs under the `pulse` user, who is part of `audio`, so any application that can talk to PulseAudio should still be able to produce sound.

Comment: @muru will make the answer. He needs the rep >:-D

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this one to know the device file. Taken from the man page of `dsp`.

> OSS  4.0  (and later) will create audio devices under
>   /dev/oss/
>          directory.  For example /dev/oss/sblive0/pcm0 is the first audio device
>          that  belongs  to  the  first Sound Blaster Live! or Audigy card in the
>          system. These direct devices are used  when  an  application  needs  to
>          access specific audio device (instead of the default one).
>
> ```
>    You  can use the ossinfo(1) utility with the -a option to get a list of
>    the available audio devices in the system.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I actually came across some references to OSS 4.0 during my initial search. However, I do not have oss listed in /dev/. I have searched for it using `ls -lah /dev`.

Comment: That's because OSS is also *old*. Ubuntu uses PulseAudio. You might have some luck disabling PA and switching to ALSA, which is not that old, but I can't help you with that.